# Java Tetris game

Tags: java, opengl, jpanel

I was thinking of making a Tetris game for Java and could not decide on how to approach drawing the different tiles.
My first idea was to use JPanels and dropping JPanels, moving them down every second by 1 and allowing the user to rotate them and such. But the problem I came across was how I was going to test whether a line had been made.

My other plan was to use OpenGL but I have no previous experience in OpenGL so I am not entirely sure how I would even go about programming the game.

**My question to you is:**
Would it be smarter to use the OpenGL path or the JPanel path? And If the JPanel path, any ideas on how I could test if a line has been made?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I would learn OpenGL as it is used in a wide variety of games.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how you are serious to make this. If you don't have more time or you want a make a simple game, you can use JPanel but my point of view JPanel doesn't have enough function to make this game properly. OpenGl is the good option. You said you has no experience in openGL. I say just study the basic openGl and basic function like transform, scale, rotation..etc. You can easily make it by this.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the time then learn OpenGL. But a game like this can also be created in something as simple as C:

1. First create an array of unique shapes;
2. At runtime you will fill them with random colors (and random orientation) and drop from the top of the screen;
3. The usable background area will anyhow we a limited area matrix and not be filled;
4. In your logic you will continually check if all cells in a single row are filled. If so you then clear them and shift all the cells above by one row below.